Как нарисовать горизонтальный график в приложении Kivy?
Необходимо создать график в приложении.
На данном этапе, я не смог найти точных описаний как строить в горизонтальном виде данный график. Я пробовал менять в points местами данные точек, также пробовал вращать canvas - но это не помогло мне добиться нужного результата. Попытка прорисовать HBar также не подошла, т.к. он рисует линию через весь график. Мне очень хотелось бы разобраться.
Код программы:
from kivy.garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot, LinePlot, BarPlot, HBar 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

class myApp(App):
    bl = Builder.load_string("""
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: [5, 5, 5, 5]
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: .15
        Label:
            id: lbl
            text: 'Метка'
            font_size: 32
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                id: btn_start
                text: 'Load'
            Button:
                id: btn_stop
                text: 'Stop'                
    Graph:
        id: graph
        xlabel: 'depth'
        ylabel: 'volume'
        y_grid_label: True
        x_grid_label: True
        font_size: 28
        x_ticks_minor: 1
        x_ticks_major: 4
        y_ticks_minor: 10
        y_ticks_major: 10
        x_grid: False
        y_grid: False
""")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.plot = HBar(color=[1, 1, 1, 1])
        self.plot_pick = BarPlot(color=[.8, 0, 0, 1])
        super(myApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.ids.btn_start.bind(on_press = self.start)
        self.root.ids.btn_stop.bind(on_press = self.stop)
        self.event=Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_data, 2.5) 
 
    def update_data(self, dt):
        self.root.ids.lbl.text = 'Создаем'
        self.plot_pick.bar_width = 25
        self.plot_pick.points = [(10, 5), (25, 11)]
        self.root.ids.graph.add_plot(self.plot_pick)
    
    def stop(self, dt):
        Clock.unschedule(self.event)
        self.root.ids.lbl.text = 'Остановлен'

    def start(self, dt):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_lbl, 2)
        self.root.ids.lbl.text = 'Восстанавливаем'

    def build(self):
        return self.bl

myApp().run()

